# Samsung printer ml-2545

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I can't find a driver for my Samsung ml-2545 monochrome printer that will work. I tried getting it from Samsung but when I install it it says:

> missing file /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertosplc

which is in my downloads folder but I can't get it into the `/usr/lib/cups/filter/` folder. I am not good with terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: If I misunderstoond this please edit your question or leave me a comment so it is more clear to  me ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you need to do this in command line:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/rasterosplc /usr/lib/cups/filter/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://www.linuxformat.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16506&start=15&sid=b452c38f53188daa180db31773b35457) to be helpful. In brief:

- Running `sudo /install.sh` in the ULD (Unified Linux Driver) folder will do everything you need, bar one thing: If you try to add your printer straight away (as outlined in the Samsung manual), the error message `missing file /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertosplc` that you saw will come up.
- However, there should be a symbolic link called `rastertospl` (note the missing 'c') in that directory. If you move to the directory in your terminal and execute `sudo ln -s rastertospl rastertosplc` and *then* add the printer (see first point), everything should be fine (it got my Samsung ML 1675 to print immediately).

Answer (score -1):

You just need to link `/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertosplc` to `rastertospl`:

```
sudo ln -s rastertospl /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertosplc
```